# How to create a google map in android using Lua?

Tags: android, lua

I am developing an app in Lua where we need to embed a google map fragment in an activity. The whole app is being developed in Lua. I want to know how we can import java google maps Api in Lua and use its methods and classes to embed a google map fragment in our activity.

Comment: I donot want to use any external SDK like Corona and want to keep the app as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a long time ago.., figured I should post it now. Lua as you know can manipulate Java objects.. So just write the entire code for displaying maps in java. No XML just pure Java code.. Then send the required objects to lua.. And then replicate the same logic in lua to manipulate the Java objects.

This will display the map but if you need to paste the map on a fragment then things can be a little tricky.. You then need to use xml